# How to obtain multiple outputs from LSTM for Seq2Seq for same input sequence?

Tags: lstm, transliteration

I have implemented an LSTM network for transliteration that is using Seq2Seq approach. But its only giving me one output sequence for a given input sequence. I can not see how can I obtain more than one output sequence and their associated probability values using an LSTM network. Or if it is even possible to obtain multiple solutions using this approach. I have a training data in form of English words and transliterations of these words in a second language other than English. I can see that people have been using LSTM for problems like next word suggestion where more than one answer is possible. So it should be possible to achieve the same for transliteration also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "beam search" method to generate variable results.

There are many materials that introduce it well and here is one written by CMU, "Neural Machine Translation and Sequence-to-sequence Models: A Tutorial", Chapter 7.2.

Recently, tensorflow seq2seq model implemented the beam search clearly, you can refer to [Tensorflow-seq2seq-BeamSearchDecoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BeamSearchDecoder).